# Don't understand closest pair heuristic from “The Algorithm Design Manual

Tags: algorithm

I have been reading Algorithm design manual.

A diﬀerent idea might be to repeatedly connect the closest pair of endpoints whose connection will not create a problem, such as premature termination of the cycle. Each vertex begins as its own single vertex chain. After merging everything together, we will end up with a single chain containing all the points in it. Connecting the ﬁnal two endpoints gives us a cycle. At any step during the execution of this closest-pair heuristic, we will have a set of single vertices and vertex-disjoint chains available to merge. In pseudocode:
 ClosestPair(P)
    Let n be the number of points in set P.
    For i = 1  to n − 1 do
        d = ∞
        For each pair of endpoints (s, t) from distinct vertex chains
            if dist(s, t) ≤ d then sm = s, tm = t, and d = dist(s, t)
        Connect (sm, tm) by an edge
    Connect the two endpoints by an edge
Please note that sm and tm should be sm and tm.

why d = ∞
?
Coluld any one please explain the nearest-neighbour tour?
Which book should I read before reading this book?

Comment: Which problem is the heuristic for? At a glance, it looks like it's for the Travelling Salesman problem. If so, you should probably mention that in your question. Also, the question might be better suited for [cs.se].

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm sets `d = ∞` so that the first comparison always succeeds: `if dist(s, t) ≤ d then ...`

An alternative would be to set d to the distance between the first pair and then try all the remaining pairs, but in terms of lines of code, that's more code.  In programming you typically use the maximum value possible for your given arithmetic type and often that is provided as a constant in the language, e.g. `Int.MaxValue`.

Comment: Thanks.I understatnd.But could you please explain NearestNeighbor(P)
Pick and visit an initial point p0 from P
p = p0
i = 0
While there are still unvisited points
i = i + 1
Select pi to be the closest unvisited point to pi−1
Visit pi
Return to p0 from pn−1

Comment: So, that's a different algorithm that simple walks from one vertex to the next until all have been visited and at each step it moves to the nearest unvisited point.  Very simple, easy to implement but unlikely to be a very good path if you are interested in minimizing the total distance.